# VBA Combobox to auto populate texboxes from data on a spreadsheet using VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am following a tutorial to populate the textboxes on my userform depending on the number selected from the combobox (the name of the combobox is cmbClientName) but I keep receiving a runtime error '-2147024809(8000700057)' Could not find the specific object.

Could someone help me to solve why this happens and also if i wanted to use string instead of numbers how can i modify. Thanks for the help. The data is on Sheet3(ClientList)

Here is my code below:

```
    Private Sub cmbClientName_Change()
Dim q, p As Long

q = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet3.Range("A:A"))
For p = 1 To 7
Me("Textbox" & p).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.cmbClientName.Value), _
Sheet3.Range("A" & 2, "H" & q), p + 1, 0)

Next p

End Sub
```

I will attach photos of my project relevant to the question.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwkgn.png)

[Userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yik8H.png)

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJ6mG.png)

Comment: Should it be `Me.Controls("Textbox" & p).Value`?

Comment: that way for some reason still doesnt work on my code But i was able to solve this another way

Comment: Hi, could you tell us what was the error ?